# Migrating from IIS 6 to IIS 7, error on startup serving .html file

Tags: .net, web-config, iis-7.5

I am currently trying to migrate to Visual Studio 2013 from 2010 and also moving my application from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5.

I have a Backbone SPA style app which uses a thin .net backend, on startup we load our index.html via IIS.  I have both both VS2013 and VS2010 up with my project, in 2010 using the "Visual Studio Development Server" (which I understand is IIS 6) the project loads and runs fine.

My web.config looks like this:

```
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
   </compilation>
     <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="153600" maxUrlLength="2048" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="chrome=1" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <!-- Make sure we can use this handler for any URL because we're using ReST. The default is
            for it to be used only for .svc -->
            <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <standardEndpoints>
            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
                <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
            </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In 2013 using "IIS Express" I get the following error first:

> There is no build provider registered for the extension '.html'. You
>   can register one in the  section in
>   machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a
>   BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value
>   'Web' or 'All'.

So I added the following to the compilation section:

```
<buildProviders >
   <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
   <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
 </buildProviders>
```

At this point I'm stuck with a new error and I can't seem to get around it, now on startup I get the following error:

> The service '/index.html' cannot be activated due to an exception
>   during compilation.  The exception message is: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object..]